# Ordering of algebraic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordered-fields

This question is closely related to [the question asked and answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2069245/28724). We can define two different orders on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

1. Can we prove that in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ there are only two orders.
2. Can we prove that any finite algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ has more than one ordering? (
   **UPDATE:** *I have missed the case for $\mathbb{Q}(\imath)$. What I have in my mind is the cases which does not contain $\imath$ as an element of the extended field. For instance what happens for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.)*

Advanced thanks for any help.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ for $d > 0$ is totally imaginary that's why it has no ordering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two orderings on $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. Any
countable ordered field can be embedded in $\Bbb R$ in an order-preserving
way, so these correspond to embeddings taking $\sqrt2$ to $\sqrt2$
and $\sqrt2$ to $-\sqrt2$.

$\Bbb Q(i)$ cannot be made into an ordered field.

In general, if $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is a number field, with $\alpha$
having minimal polynomial $f$, the orderings of $K$ correspond
to the real zeros of $f$.

Comment: And those [real embeddings and closure of number fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25734/is-there-a-purely-algebraic-criterion-which-characterizes-the-real-algebraic-num) have non-trivial properties

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Any ordering of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ gives rise to an embedding into $\Bbb R$ and there are only two if these.
   Concretely, whether $a+b\sqrt 2$ is positive can be determined from whether or not $\sqrt 2$ is positive.
2. No. $\Bbb Q[i]$ has no ordering at all.